# How to store user defined settings for a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that takes a list of words from a user. This list is the same list that the user will use for ever and consists of about 40 words. I want the user to be able to save this list so it can be used in further sessions. Because it is 40 words it is too long to be used as a bookmark. What other solutions are there for such a problem?

My code so far:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

   #  title
   titlePanel("How do I store the text for reuse?"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(),

      mainPanel(
        textInput("caption", "", ""),
        actionBttn("myText",label = "Store my text",size="sm")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$myText,{

    input$caption #<-Where can I store this for later use in a separate session?



  },ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: did you have a look here? https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html no need to put it in the url

Comment: What's about? https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html